# view.invalidate not working on phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-view

I have a Custom view, made up of several view and label components. When the user touches the view, I draw a frame around the view to indicate selected status, and the background changes on double tap. The frame is drawn using the overridden draw function of the view by passing the view a frame color different from the background and calling view.invalidate(). Same for the background change.

This used to work perfectly as long as I was developing for API 7. Even on my phone that runs API 16. I recently migrated the code to API 11+ and now the selected frame is not showing anymore and the background does not change on my phone even though it is still working in the emulator (API 14).

A afternoon of trying to trace where the error is, I figured out that on my phone, calling view.invalidate() is not triggering a redraw of the view. I also tried view.requestLayout() and view.postInvalidate() (just to make sure) with the same result. Putting the invalidate command in a separate thread did not work either.

To summarize:
Code API 7 - Phone API 16 - Emulator API 7 to 14 view.invalidate works
Code API 11 - Phone API 16 - Emulator API 11 to 14 view.invalidate does not work on Phone but on emulator.

I have a Motorola RAZR M from Verizon

Is this a known bug or was there a change in handling of things like that in API 11?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried removing the hardware acceleration for your view `theView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it worked. Just out of curiosity, why did't I have to do this when the code was API 7?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably the min SDK version imposes some defaults for the hardware acceleration. With a minimum of 7 the acceleration was most likely disabled for the app no matter the version, but starting with a minimum of 11(when the hardware acceleration was introduced) that acceleration is set to be used.